# Select a row, and the rows either side of it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm putting together a blog with posts which implement JSON API. To that end, when I retrieve a post from the database, I want to include links to the next and previous posts. For the database this means that when I retrieve a row from a `posts` table, I'd like to also retrieve the row before and the row after it.

I'm a bit of a noob with SQL (specifically postgres). At the moment I have the following:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM posts 
  WHERE id >= (
    SELECT id 
    FROM posts 
    WHERE id < (
      SELECT id
      FROM posts
      WHERE slug = 'the-slug'
    )
    AND published = TRUE
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
  AND published = TRUE
  ORDER BY id ASC
  LIMIT 3;
```

(`posts` have serial `id` primary key, a `published` boolean, and a `slug` varchar)

All I have access to is the slug of the centre post. This works, but obviously breaks if `the-slug` represents the first published row. It also seems quite naive. Is there a better way to go about this?

EDIT:

I'm trying to avoid this question being too specific to my problem so that any answers might be of more use to many. However, the above is quite loose. Consider the table to be created with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    slug VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    published BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);
```

There are more columns, but they should be of no relevance to this question. I'm trying to find, given a slug, the row that matches that slug and the rows before and after it (where they exist). I'm trying to achieve:

- If no slug matches, no rows.
- If a slug matches a post, and it is the first published post...

  - One row if only one post is published.
  - Two rows (the first and second) if more than one post is published.
- If a slug matches a post, and it is the last published post...

  - One row if only one post is published.
  - Two rows (the second to last and the last) if more than one post is published.
- If a slug matches a post and it is not the first or the last published post...

  - Three rows (the row before the matching row, the row, and the row after the matching row).

Comment: Take a look at LAG and LEAD functions

Comment: ... or use a window function with ROWS between preceding/following.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The question was quite loose. I've added some clarification. Please let me know if there's more I can do to clarify.

Comment: An easy solution that get's all the information in a single row, could look like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ba741/1 this could probably be extended to get the full rows as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh, I like that! I think an adaptation of that's going to be the answer. If you write it up I'll mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very hacky way to do it:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM posts 
 WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
      FROM posts
     WHERE slug = 'the-slug'
    UNION

    SELECT id+1
      FROM posts
     WHERE slug = 'the-slug'
    UNION

    SELECT id-1
      FROM posts
     WHERE slug = 'the-slug'
    )
   AND published = TRUE
 ORDER BY id ASC
 LIMIT 3;
```

There may be a more efficient way with LAG and LEAD options.

Comment: Please see my clarification on the question. The problem is that I'm looking only for published posts, so incrementing or decrementing the id is not going to work in general. i.e. the ids may not be sequential. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Then what's wrong with this:

    SELECT * FROM posts WHERE slug = 'the-slug' ORDER by id ASC LIMIT 3;

Comment: The slug has a unique constraint. I'm after the published row which matches the slug, and the rows (also published) before and after it. These will have different slugs (see the `CREATE TABLE` in the question).

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()` function:

- number all *published* rows (add `rn` to `posts` in the first query),
- find row number of the searched slug (`row_found` in the second query),
- select rows with `rn >= row_found- 1 and rn <= row_found+ 1`.

---

```
with numbered_posts as (        
    select *, row_number() over (order by id) rn
    from posts
    where published),
post_found as (
    select rn row_found
    from numbered_posts
    where slug = 'the-slug')
select id, slug, published
from numbered_posts
cross join post_found
where rn >= row_found- 1 and rn <= row_found+ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `LAG` and `LEAD`, where `'the-slug'` if the slug to centre around:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    slug,
    LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS prev_id,
    LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS next_id,
    LAG(slug) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS prev_slug,
    LEAD(slug) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS next_slug
  FROM posts
  WHERE published = TRUE
) t
WHERE slug = 'the-slug'
;
```

It returns a single row (if the slug matches a row at all), with some additional columns with data borrowed from the published row before and published row after (where they exist); `prev_id`, `prev_slug`, `next_id`, and `next_slug`.

This answer is very slightly adapted from a comment on the question given by a_horse_with_no_name which points to [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ba741/1) (if you post the answer I'll mark it as the correct one).